# onPress not working on Expo Go but is working on Desktop simulator

Tags: react-native, expo, onpress

inside the autocomplete i have the onPress that ends up setting the address to the one I click on. and it works on the desktop sim that i have. but on Expo Go it doesn't recognize a touch at all.

```
 <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
          placeholder="Type an address..."
          fetchDetails={true}
          onPress={(data, details = null) => {
              console.log(details.formatted_address);
            if (details && details.formatted_address) {
              setAddressInput(details.formatted_address);
              setAddressValid(true);
            }
          }}
          query={{
            key: apiKey,
            language: "en",
            components: "country:us",
            types: "address",
          }}
          styles={{
            container: styles.address_input_container,
            textInput: [
              styles.address_input,
              !isAddressValid && styles.address_input_invalid,
            ],
            listView: styles.suggestions_list,
            separator: {
              height: 1,
              backgroundColor: "silver",
            },
            description: styles.suggestion_item,
          }}
          listViewDisplayed="auto"
        />
```

i thought it was the onpress because that is what wasn't firing. but now i see that it has to do with the Expo Go because it does work on the desktop sim version.

the only other thing I think it could be is just that because I have the keyboard up. it won't let me click anything. but then when i click on anything the keyboard goes away. but so does the suggested list